# Миллисекунды в минуты и секунды

Tags: php

**200456** - миллисекунды
**3,34093333** - это минут и секунды в 200456 миллисекундах

Как на PHP получить из **200456** мииллисекунд получить **3,34**?

Comment: 1 секунда = 1000 милисекунд, 1 минута = 60 секунд 200456 / 1000 = 200,456 200,456 / 60 = 3,3409(3) или 3,34093333. Для информации.

Comment: 3,34093333 - это НЕ "минут и секунды", а просто минут. Минут и секунд будет 3.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно разделить миллисекунды на `60000`.

```
$minutes = round(200456 / 60000, 2);
```